# Over-riding methods remove decorators inherited from base class

Tags: python, python-decorators

```
class X():
    @decorator
    def method(self):
        return

class Y(X):
    def method(self):
        return
```

Is there any way where the applied decorators still applies on child class `method` without explicitly decorating them?

Comment: Not really. When you over-ride a method, you replace it completely. Of course, you can use `super` to access the original parent method, if you need it.

Comment: OTOH, you could create a class decorator that looks for methods by name, and applies decorators to them. (And I suspect you could do something similar using a metaclass). But that sounds like it would lead to unreadable code. It's better to make it explicit which methods are decorated.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, since overriding methods creates a completely new object. It is the same logic that `super(...).__init__` does not get called automatically, and the general Python guideline of be explicit - for example, if that happened by default, but you did not want the decorator, how would it work?

Does not seem like too much work to be explicit here, and decorate.

Comment: That said, Python is very hacky. Likely you could code something that does this, but I do not think it should be a part of any answer.